# select values from first table not present in second table in spark using scala or spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a sample hive/spark table as below:

| row_key | data_as_of_date | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20210121 | key1 | value1 |
| A | 20210121 | key2 | value2 |
| A | 20210121 | key3 | value3 |
| B | 20210121 | key1 | value1 |
| B | 20210121 | key2 | value1 |
| B | 20210121 | key3 | value2 |
| B | 20210121 | key4 | value3 |
| C | 20210121 | key1 | value2 |

...and goes on.

I have another hive/spark table with same columns. Sample data below:

| row_key | data_as_of_date | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20210121 | key1 | value1 |
| A | 20210121 | key2 | value2 |
| B | 20210121 | key1 | value1 |
| B | 20210121 | key4 | value3 |
| C | 20210121 | key1 | value2 |

`row_key` is the joining column between these 2 tables and same `row_key` can repeat in multiple rows in both the tables.

I am struggling in writing spark sql query or using spark dataframe to show/select all the rows from table 1 which have `key` column value not present in table 2 joining on the `row_key`.

For the sample data the result should be:

| row_key | data_as_of_date | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20210121 | key3 | value3 |
| B | 20210121 | key2 | value1 |
| B | 20210121 | key3 | value2 |

Please help with the spark sql query or dataframe operations in scala.

Let me know if any more Info. is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do a leftanti join on two dataframes to get the expected output.

```
 val df = Seq(("A","20210121","key1","value1"),("A","20210121","key2","value2"),("A","20210121","key3","value3"),("B","20210121","key1","value1"),("B","20210121","key2","value1"),("B","20210121","key3","value3"),("B","20210121","key4","value3"),("C","20210121","key1","value2"))
.toDF("row_key","data_as_of_date","key","value")

 val df1 = Seq(("A","20210121","key1","value1"),("A","20210121","key2","value2"),("B","20210121","key1","value1"),("B","20210121","key4","value3"),("C","20210121","key1","value2"))
.toDF("row_key","data_as_of_date","key","value")

 val outputdf = df.join(df1, Seq("row_key","data_as_of_date","key"),"leftanti")
 display(outputdf)
```

You can see the output as below :
[image]